Environmental variables from ENV are not picked up if ENV set in helm chart
I have a deployment.yaml where I want to set an ENV varibale to source a list of other env variables, but it does not work, although when I login to running container the variables are there, but my script does not pick them up. If I set them separately everything is ok.
deployment.yaml
        env:
          - name: ENV
            value: /vault/secrets/config

Dockerfile
FROM golang:1.22-alpine  as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
CMD sleep infinity
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o app  ./cmd/k8s-workshop/main.go


FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/app ./app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ./app


so the .app needs a VERY_SECRET variable to start, but it does not find it
/vault/secrets/config
#!/bin/sh
set -e
export VERY_SECRET=vaultworks2

exec "$@"

Inside the container
 kubectl exec -n ws -it k8s-workshop2-6bc98bd845-5ksgv -- /bin/sh
/ # echo $VERY_SECRET
vaultworks2
/ # echo $ENV
/vault/secrets/config

I do not know it this important, the content of /vault/secrets/config comes from vault sidecar container injector, as described here
So the full deployment.yaml looks like this
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: k8s-workshop2
  name: k8s-workshop2
  namespace: ws
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: k8s-workshop2
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-vault: workshop/data/ws1
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-config: |

          {{- with secret "workshop/data/ws1" -}}

          #!/bin/sh
          set -e

          {{- range $key, $value := .Data.data }}
          export {{ $key }}={{ $value }}
          {{- end }}

          exec "$@"
          {{- end }}
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: ws_role
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: k8s-workshop2
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: ENV
              value: /vault/secrets/config
          image: cr.gitlab.com/services/k8s-workshop/workshop-k8s:tag
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: k8s-workshop2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080


Nothing you show in the question would create a /vault/secrets directory, run that script, or try to set $VERY_SECRET.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre]?

I edited it, but as I wrote the file is there and I showed its content, I am not sure it is really important how it is created.

Do you need to set Kubernetes command: (overriding Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT) to run the injected script?  It sounds like you're seeing a clear error when your application starts up, but note that kubectl exec will not go via this path and you won't necessarily be able to see the environment variable outside your program itself.

Actually, I would like to avoid editing entrypoint or Dockerfile, because this all is a part of my helm templates, and I want them to be compatible with any container in the end. Yes, when my application starts variable seems to be empty, but I do not understand why and if it is possible to fix it.

You set an environment variable $ENV; what uses it?  The question that you link to actually has several examples, including how you might set command: or args:.  The examples that use $ENV or $BASH_ENV seem to assume the main container command runs a shell somewhere along the way; POSIX.1 specifies that $ENV is only read for interactive shells.
